# iOS: print unicode character in decimal notation

Tags: ios, unicode, char

How would I print a string with 1 letter in a decimal form?
I need to get unique integer for a character and convert it to string.

```
NSString* letter = @"a"; // ---> to @"97"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unichar c = [letter characterAtIndex:0];
NSString *charAsNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",c];
```